Change ASP.NET Core validation css class names on server side
I'm using Razor Pages (v8). When a form fails validation and the page is rerendered, fields are annotated with input-validation-error and input-validation-valid. Since I'm using bootstrap, I need is-invalid and is-valid instead.
I do not want a js hack/solution. Is there a way to change the css class names on the server side? Perhaps a customisation hook somewhere during startup?

I just discovered that the framework uses hardcoded values for those css classes. So I don't think this is currently possible.
I posted a feature request for a customisation hook during startup.
If you also need this functionality, please upvote that issue.
If there is some way to accomplish this currently, please add your answer and I'll accept it.
